# Unable to get correct letters when sending special characters to the printer in Java

Tags: java, printing

I am writing a program that are working with adresses and I want the final output to be sent to a printer. As most of the adresses are located in northen Europe I need to be able to handle some special characters. However I seem to be unable to do this when printing.
When writing to the terminal or to a *.txt file everything works fine but on the printed pages I get gibberish.
This is basicly what I am trying to do:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.print.*;

public class PrintExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws PrintException,IOException {

         String testData = "ÅÄÖ, åäö";

         PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
         InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(testData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
         DocFlavor flavor =  DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
         DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
         Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);

         job.print(doc, null);

         is.close();
     }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue as to what's wrong?

Comment: Could you try by passing the byte array instead of a stream, and using `DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8`  ?

Comment: Tried with a byte array but gets "sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor" when useing

    DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.TEXT_HTML_UTF_8
gets an ourput when useing

    DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE
but still the same nonsense characters.

Comment: I meant TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8, not TEXT_HTML_UTF_8 .

Comment: Sorry, meant TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8. Same error.

Comment: Hi @Tzun, did you ever solve this problem? I'm in the same siruation